# Test for a difference of slopes

Tags: statistical-significance, small-sample, trend

This seems like a basic question, and I feel kind of dumb that the answer is not obvious to me.

The data look like this:

Four count variables, all subtypes of a class of event--car crashes (A, B, C, D, and the total of these four, T) observed annually.

A traffic flow variable, F, also measured for each year. It follows a generally increasing trend, though it is not perfectly monotonic.

Thus for each year, it is possible to calculate various rates: T/F, A/F, (B+C+D)/F, etc.

There are only seven years of data. The data are measured at a city level. Thus, there is only one observation per year.

T/F follows a "safety in numbers" relationship. If you scatterplot it against F, it follows a generally decreasing trend. Also, because F is related to time, you can plot T/F over time and observe the same decreasing trend. (I mention this because I keep confusing myself about whether I should be looking at the relationship between the rate and F or between the rate and time).

I am interested in whether A/F follows the same "safety in numbers" trend as B/F, C/F, and D/F (or alternately, as (B+C+D)/F or T/F). One problem here is that I'm not sure about the right comparison.

The heuristic way to assess this is just to fit a line through the scatterplots of each of individual rate v F.

But what then? They are almost certainly different. Are they different enough? Maybe A/F could follow a "danger in numbers" trend (have a positive slope). But that could be due to chance.

Keeping in mind that I have only seven data points, I want to know if there is a statistical way to test the difference in these slopes. It seems like maybe there is an ANOVA trend analysis approach, but I can't conceptualize it.

Comment: So, having thought about it some, as long as I'm comparing outcomes that are not related or nested (e.g., A/F vs T/F), I can treat these as independent samples. I found a statistical test (t-test) for a difference in slopes here: http://www.real-statistics.com/regression/hypothesis-testing-significance-regression-line-slope/comparing-slopes-two-independent-samples/